# iOS Keyboard to change font,size,colour

Tags: ios, custom-controls, uikeyboard

I am wanting to make iOS custom keyboard to change UITextfield font , colour & Text.
Not sure if there is any standard method/code.
I have got some hint from [here](https://github.com/YuAo/WUEmoticonsKeyboard)

Can somebody suggest a better method to achieve all these?
Note: Basically i want it to appear like the way it appears in tools.
      say if I am choosing font from font list then all fonts must have font style as per their name, and colour option must be square button of colour itself. etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see the below links about custom keyboards

http://mayfleet.com/2012/12/14/ios-custom-keyboard/

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/